# Interaction in regression

Tags: regression, interaction

[image]In my regression model of BMR on age (yrs) , gender (1=male, 0=female), height and weight. The regression equation obtained is:

BMR = 1232.059+13.281 weight+3.954 age+192.214 male-3.471 age:gender.

Please interpret the negative coefficient of age:gender interaction. Do the negative coefficient have anything to do with the positive coefficient of age and gender?

Comment: When you say "had a negative regression" do you mean "had a negative coefficient"?

Comment: Yes.BMR = 1232.059+13.281 weight+3.954 age+192.214 male-3.471 age:gender

Comment: Can you edit the information into your question, please?

Comment: How are `gender` and `male` related? Are they the same? Is `age` a factor, or "age in years"?

Comment: it might help to draw a graph of age/bmr with two lines - one for men and one for women.

Comment: The tendency for the dispersion of the residuals about each line to increase linearly with *decreasing* age suggests regressing 1/bmr against age.  In other words, there is some evidence that perhaps this ratio should be taken in the other order.